# how to rewrite the following function so that it is no longer vulnerable to stack buffer overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I need to rewrite the function so that it is no longer vulnerable to stack buffer overflow.

```
void hello (char *tag)
{
   char inp [16];

   printf("enter value for %s:", tag);
   gets(inp);
   printf("hello your %s is %s\n", tag, inp);
}
```

Also, 
how do I rewrite the following other code to avoid buffer overflow:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    int valid=FALSE;
    char str1[8];
    char str2[8];

    next_tag(str1);
    gets(str2);
    if (strncmp(str1,str2,8)==0)
        valid=TRUE;
    printf("buffer: str1(%s),str2(%s),valid(%d) \n", str1, str2, valid);
}
```

Comment: title in CAPS -> gimmeh-teh-code question

Comment: similar to previously asked question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471896/buffer-overflow-correction-please

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) instead of gets().  It allows you to limit the number of characters stored in the buffer.

Comment: what about the second program with buffer overflow, do i use fgets instead of gets(str2) ?

Comment: @Julian Yes - you should never, ever use gets().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to post code as this looks like homework.

Buffer Overflow happens when you try to access a location of the buffer beyond its size.

for example, in your `hello(...)` function this would be trying to access an element of the array `inp` larger than 15.

You ask for the user to provide an index into the array and then gives back the value of that location of the array.

Inorder to prevent an overflow you invariably need to make sure that the range of the index user specified is below the size of that array.

I can't comment on the second code fragment because it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) instead of gets.  Keep the size at the length of the buffer and you won't overflow it.

Comment: In `fgets` it's enough just to pass the size of the buffer (without the -1), since it "reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n".

Answer (score 0):

```
void hello (char *tag)
{
   char inp [16];

   printf("enter value for %s:", tag);
   fgets(inp, 16, stdin);
   printf("hello your %s is %s\n", tag, inp);
}
```

And similar for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test case after receiving the strings to check its length.
If you accept the input then proceed otherwise terminate or panic!
   
 Do Tests before this line:

```
if (strncmp(str1,str2,8)==0)
    valid=TRUE;
```