# buffer overflow correction please

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

i want to avoid buffer overflow vulnerability in the following program,

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[ ]) {    
  int valid=FALSE;     
  char str1[8];     
  char str2[8];      
  next_tag(str1);     
  gets(str2);    
  if (strncmp(str1,str2,8)==0)      
    valid=TRUE;     
  printf("buffer: str1(%s),str2(%s),valid(%d) \n", str1, str2, valid); 
}
```

is this the right correction to it in order to fix vulnerability?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[ ]) {     
  int valid=FALSE;     
  char str1[8];     
  char str2[8];      
  next_tag(str1);     
  fgets(str2);       /* HERE IS THE CHANGE! */
  if (strncmp(str1,str2,8)==0)        
    valid=TRUE;     
  printf("buffer: str1(%s),str2(%s),valid(%d) \n", str1, str2, valid); 
}
```

Comment: Please look at the documentation for the function before you start using it.

Comment: You could have flagged the change so that all the readers didn't have to vgrep the teo to see the difference :(. No, it's not the right correction. How did you expect fgets to know big your buffer was? As Ignacio says, read the documentation for fgets

Comment: for those who don't want to look extensively, so only difference if `gets` vs `fgets`

Comment: I tried to make the change stand out a bit. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I REWRITE THE FOLLOWING function so that it is no longer vulnerable to stack buffer overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471306/how-do-i-rewrite-the-following-function-so-that-it-is-no-longer-vulnerable-to-sta)

Answer (score 2):

```
  fgets(str2, 8, STDIN);
```

fgets takes three arguments:

str

- Pointer to an array of chars where
  the string read is stored.

num

- Maximum number of characters to be
  read (including the final
  null-character). Usually, the length
  of the array passed as str is used.

stream

- Pointer to a FILE object that
  identifies the stream where
  characters are read from. To read
  from the standard input, stdin can be
  used for this parameter.

see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I should point out is why your first implementation has a buffer overflow.

```
// Allocate a char array that can hold 'max' 8 characters.
char str2[8];

// Ask user for input and stuff it into str2. If the user
// gives us more than 8 characters, we will end up overwriting
// str2 beyond its allocated buffer. 
gets(str2);
```

So what we need is a way to tell 'gets', to get **no more than 8** characters. fgets helps us solve this. It takes for a parameter, the maximum number of characters to read. Look at Vladimir's post for more details about [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).